# Powershell chmod on /tmp/hive for winutils and hadoop/spark

Tags: windows, powershell, hadoop, apache-spark

I'm currently trying to incorporate a process for setting up Spark/Hadoop on a teststack into our powershell script.

It's a windows environment and a few bits are throwing curveballs, but thsi is the worst :)

When I manually install I can run `%HADOOP_HOME%\bin\winutils.exe chmod 777 /tmp/hive` from the command line but I now need to translate that into Powershell script, is this possible at all?  I've serached but not yet come across a solution.  One post suggested using icacls but then /tmp/hive is not allowed as the arg.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: %HADOOP_HOME% would be smth like: (Get-Childitem env:HADOOP_HOME).Value . not sure if Start-Process would be the best choice in your case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the PowerShell environment variable syntax (`$env:VARIABLE`) instead of the batch syntax (`%VARIABLE%`) should suffice. Note that you must use the call operator for this to work. I'd also recommend adding double quotes in case there are spaces in the path.

```
& "${env:HADOOP_HOME}\bin\winutils.exe" chmod 777 /tmp/hive
```

The need for the call operator appears to be due to PowerShell's command parser not recognizing an expression `$variable\something` as a path. Without the `&` you'd be getting an an exception

> Unexpected token '\bin\winutils.exe' in expression or statement.

Comment: Thank you for taking the tie to answer, much appreciated! :)